# Adding autocomplete-like html panel under textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I need to develop some additional panel for the textbox that will be opened on textbox focus under the textbox. It will have ok and close buttons, and the textbox will be updated according to selection that was made.

Something that will be opened like an autocomplete feature but will consist of some dynamic html (buttons/textboxes and simple html stuff).

Do you know some existing pluggins / jsfiddle examples of something similar?

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a mock-up of what you want in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you could get some use out of this small test I came up with.

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/s4kon9L5/)

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.choice {
    visibility:hidden;
    height:auto;
    width:170px;
    background:#3CF;
}
</style>
<script>
function openSelect() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
    for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
        element[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
function closeSelect() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
    for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
        element[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("group1");
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            radioVar = (radios[i].value);
            document.getElementById("result").value = radioVar;
            break;
        } else if (radios[3].checked) {
            document.getElementById("result").input.value;
        }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="result" placeholder="select" onFocus="openSelect();">
<div class="choice">
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item1" value="Milk">
<label for="item1">Milk</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item2" value="Butter">
<label for="item2">Butter</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item3" value="Cheese">
<label for="item3">Cheese</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item4" value="">
<label for="item3">Other (input type)</label>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Done" onClick="closeSelect();">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Boltosaurus I decided to add a little more functionality to the code above. Hope you like it!